# Передать функцию по сокетам из iframe в конструктор сайта

Tags: javascript, функции, iframe, сокеты, tilda

Всем привет!

Есть трудность с передачей функции из iframe на сайт конструктора tilda.
Бьюсь уже довольно долго с этой задачей. По сокетам отправляю alert или window.open, и это срабатывает. А передать функцию не удается.

- Куда нужно смотреть, подскажите? Гуглил, пробовал разные методы, но как-то не дало результатов.
- Может в tilda дело?
- Был ли опыт такого, какие решения могут помочь?

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _По сокетам отправляю alert или window.open, и это срабатывает_? Что значит _передать функцию_? Покажи как отправляешь/принимаешь, приведи пример, когда твой подход работает с `alert`/`open` и не работает с другими функциями.

Comment: На сайте написана функция, с использованием части кода самой тильды. Я с айфрейма отправляю название функции. В конструкторе она не срабатывает. В тоже время если я отправлю алерт, то он покажется. Или релоад, то он перезагрузит страницу.

Comment: что за конструктор имеется ввиду? Кто принимает/обрабатывает твою посылку?

Comment: серверная часть: nodejs, socket.io, express, размещен на heroku. Есть айфрейм на сайте конструктор tilda и на этом сайте стоит скрипт:
function alll() {
setTimeout(function () {$('.toolate').click(); }, 2000);
}

Comment: globalThis.alll() я отправляю это, и оно не срабатывает

Comment: Что значит "отправляю это"? Что именно и как ты передаешь? Кто принимает твой ответ, что с этим ответом дальше происходит?

Comment: globalThis.alll() название функции, Функция активирует попап который принадлежит конструктору.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112227/discussion-between-grundy-and-o-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение, которое работает с разных доменов, по https.
Спасибо Grundy за подсказку. Получилась!

**Страница 1:**  iframe.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Айфрэйм с кнопкой, и сообщением для родителя</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function iframe_popup() {
window.top.postMessage('soobshenie', '*')
  }
</script>
    <input type="button" onclick="iframe_popup()" value="Кнопка!">
</body>

</html>
```

**Страница 2:**  index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Страница со слушателем из айфрэма</title>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="./iframe.html"></iframe>
    <script>
    window.onmessage = function(event) {
        if (event.data == 'soobshenie') {
            alert('Сообщение прослушано!');
        }
    };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```